# DOM does not work after calling a function

Tags: javascript

I use DOM to create Collapse like this, this is work

```
function createCollapse() {
    var btn = document.createElement("Button");
    btn.className = "collapsible";
    var name = document.createTextNode("text");
    btn.appendChild(name);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);    
}
```

I try to read the string from file and using for loop to generate it, but it doesn't work

```
function read() {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var str = fs.readFileSync('./123.txt', 'utf8');
    return str;
}

function createCollapse() {
    var str = read()
    for (i in str){
        var btn = document.createElement("Button");
        btn.className = "collapsible";
        var name = document.createTextNode(str[i]);
        btn.appendChild(name);
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
    }    
}
```

Even though I just call the function only, it can't create the normal Collapse

```
//function read() same as above

function createCollapse() {
    var str = read()   //only call read()
    var btn = document.createElement("Button");
    btn.className = "collapsible";
    var name = document.createTextNode("text");
    btn.appendChild(name);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);    
}
```

Comment: Wait wait wait... So I'm pretty sure `const fs = require("fs")` is `Node.js` so how do you get a server side language to create a DOM element? Or are you using some kind of framework like electron?

Comment: So if you know the `fs` part is working, please post a working version with only HTML, CSS, JavaScript so I can test stuff.